# Nielsen–Thurston classification and configuration spaces

Tags: reference-request, mapping-class-groups, braid-groups, configuration-spaces

Viewing the $n$-strand braid group as the mapping class group of an $n$-punctured disk, braids can be classified as periodic, reducible, or pseudo-Anosov. The same group is also the fundamental group of the $n$th unordered configuration space of the disk. Is there a description of this classification of braids that makes reference only to the topology of the configuration space?

Comment: A very partial answer is given by a theorem of Kra saying that a point-pushing mapping class is pseudo-Anosov if and only if it fills the surface.  In your situation, this would apply to braids where all but one of the points stays fixed.  See here: I. Kra, On the Nielsen-Thurston-Bers type of some self-maps of Riemann surfaces, Acta Math. 146 (1981), no. 3-4, 231–270.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? A periodic braid has a clear topological meaning: It's a curve such that a loop winding around $n$ times bounds a disc for some $n>0$. The reducible ones are exactly the ones in the image of some maps $B_n \times B_m \to B_{n+m-1}$, or something like those which arise from some natural coverings of configuration space. And the pseudo-Anosov ones are exactly the ones that don't fall into the two previous classes. These are all topological descriptions. Is the situation that the first two are satisfactory but you want a different characterization of pseudo-Anosovs?